# batch file inserts incorrect data with cyrillic font in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, encoding, batch-file

I have a simple batch which inserts a specific record to sql db:

```
set /P theuserinput="Enter the filename: "
sqlite3 test "insert into films (title, date, start_time) values ('%theuserinput%', '%date%', '%time%');"
```

it works fine with Latin filenames but when I try using it with cyrillic filenames it inserts some unreadable characters.

It turns out it worked ok, I just have to view those cyrillic records in SQLite Maestro, not in sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the codepage before executing the sqlite insert to a cyrillic pgae `chcp 855`

Or to 65001 UTF-8, but then you need to block your commands

```
set /P theuserinput="Enter the filename: "
(
  chcp 65001
  sqlite3 test "insert into films (title, date, start_time) values ('%theuserinput%', '%date%', '%time%');" 
  chcp 850
)
```